# Avoid multiple form submissions

Tags: javascript, frontend, forms

What is the Magento way to avoid multiple form submissions? Ideally I'd like to disable the submit button on the form "submit" action and set a flag to check if the form has been already submitted.

But looking at Magento's VarienForm I've seen there is already a hook for the submit option, so I was dubious if it's ok to reuse that action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working now, what I've done is using jQuery to hook on `myForm.submit()` action as follows:

```
var myForm = new VarienForm('my-form-id', false);
var formAlreadySubmitted = false;
$j('#my-form-id').submit(function(e){
   if(myForm.validator.validate()){
      if(formAlreadySubmitted){
         e.preventDefault();
            return false;
         }
         var submitChildren = $j(this).find('button[type=submit]');
         submitChildren.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
         submitChildren.addClass('disabled');
         formAlreadySubmitted = true;
    }
});
```

Notice that I'm **only disabling** the `submit` button **if the form passes Magento validation**, so to give them the chance to correct the form if it's invalid.

Comment: I've done something similar with the 'add to cart' button that involves ajax.  I just disabled the button before I submitted the ajax request and reenabled the button when I got an ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

Update in Magento 2, my script in my `.phtml` is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        "jquery"
    ], function ($) {
        var myForm = $('#inquiry-form');
        var formAlreadySubmitted = false;
        myForm.submit(function (e) {
            if (myForm.validation("isValid")) {
                if (formAlreadySubmitted) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
                var submitChildren = $(this).find('button[type=submit]');
                submitChildren.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                submitChildren.addClass('disabled');
                formAlreadySubmitted = true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```